# How to make Owl Carousel work only on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have the following html:

```
<div class="experience-items">
   <div class="experience-item">Lorem</div>
   <div class="experience-item">Lorem</div>
   <div class="experience-item">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

I want Owl Carousel to work only on mobile. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var checkWidth = $(window).width();
if (checkWidth > 699) {
  $('.experience-items').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
  $('.experience-items').find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
} else 
  if (checkWidth < 700) {
    $carousel.owlCarousel();
    owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(e) {});
  }
```

I felt like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817411/destroy-and-initialize-owl-carousel-based-on-viewport-size) was the closest to what I want to achieve, but the OP uses enquire.js, and I don't want to.

I found an example of what I want to achieve [here](http://www.s-trip.com/parents/#!/Fun+&+Safe), but I am not understanding the javascript behind it.

**UPDATE**
I found the perfect example [here](http://www.design-fluide.com/wp-content/demos/owl-slider/initialize-destroy-slider-resize.html). I won't close the topic in case someone else needs to see this. I am not sure exactly if the amount of javascript is needed, but I had to include it all and the `.bp-` classes to make it work.

Comment: It would be great if you can self-answer your question with what you found. But don't just add a link - describe everything you did and include just the code required to do this.

Comment: Also, did you see this question? It looks similar to what you were trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251644/disabling-owl-carousel-at-a-specific-viewport-width

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS media queries.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 736px) {
  .experience-items{display:none;}
}
```

*Note: We just use CSS to HIDE owl carousal.*

Comment: What if you want the items to show, but let's say like 3 columns. When on mobile, don't show it like this, but instead initialize carousel for 1 item per column and left/right navigation ..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.experience-items{
  display:block;
}
    
@media screen and (max-width:360px){
  .experience-items{
    display:block;
    }
}
```

you have to insert this css into your existing css